# .NET C# models to Knockout.js scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, code-generation, scaffolding

I'd like to have a scaffold that would create my empty knockout client models for me so I don't have to write them. This can be done at design time to fit my needs. **I do use the knockout.mapping.js** plug-in but I really need an empty model definition on the client side and the mapping plugin doesn't really help me with this.

Does anyone know if such a scaffold exists for Visual Studio? This would save me a lot of time if it did.

Just for clarity I'm looking that could take something like this C#

```
public class DocumentClient 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long DocumentClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual long DocumentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocumentId")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Document Document { get; set; }

    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public ClientRole ClientRole { get; set; }
}
```

and turn it into this knockout out model

```
function DocumentClient(documentId, clientId, clientRole) {
    var self = this;
    self.DocumentId = ko.observable(documentId);
    self.ClientId = ko.observable(clientId);
    self.ClientRole = ko.observable(clientRole);
}
```

Comment: Why not implement an own code generator? It should be really simple - some reflection and string generation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could swear I've seen a NuGet package that has this, but in the mean time, [here is a VS2012 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/32c15a80-1c54-4e96-a83f-7cd57573a5d2) that should do what you're asking.

Comment: Cool. I'll check this out. I won't mark as answered until I've had a chance! Good answer so far!

Comment: At first this wasn't working for me at all. But the author just pushed a new version and it seems to work as advertised. I am going to spread this all my other .NET + Knockout.js == <3 buddies.